# (Linux) How are files passed into applications?

Tags: linux, file

I was just wondering how files are opened in applications when the user doubles clicks the files.

I understand that it's past in as a parameter, but how would I tell my application "Load this file" when it's passed?

I'm just looking to see how it works really.

Thanks for your time.

Nathan.

Comment: It really depends on the language your application is written in.

Comment: @choroba: I think the question is aimed at determining how the shell/GUI decides what program to open files with.

Comment: I was looking at how the file pointer is passed to the application when the file is double clicked and loaded by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as in Windows, this is entirely dependent on the application.  For clicking on a file to work as you describe, the desktop environment has to be told about the association between the file and the application.  It also has to be told what command line to use to invoke the applicaton.

On Linux, most GUI desktop environments start by consulting the MIME types configuration info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME

Comment: Yeah, ok. looks like my head will be back into the GNOME documentation :D

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes its passed on as a simple $1 variable. Just as an example, open your terminal and launch firefox with this:

```
firefox http://stackoverflow.com
```

So if you save the hyperlink to your desktop and simply click the link it may just append that as a variable. However, this may not be the case for all apps.